# Error: Getter not found: "variable". Dart y Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente error a la hora de utilizar la variable `emailAccount` en el Drawer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainDrawer({
    Key key,
    this.emailAccount
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String emailAccount;
  @override
  _MainDrawerState createState() => _MainDrawerState();
}

class _MainDrawerState extends State<MainDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: const <Widget>[
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white
            ),
            accountName: Text(
                "Account Name",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.black
              ),
            ),
            accountEmail: Text(
              emailAccount,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: Colors.black
              ),
            ),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(

            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.message),
            title: Text('Message'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Profile'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

El problema es que al pasar la variable emailAccount al Text lanza el error `Error: Getter not found: 'emailAccount'.` He probado con un StatelessWidget y sigue sin funcionar. Alguna idea?

Comment: seguramente le estás pasando nulo

Comment: solucionado! Simplemente es que el children del List View estaba constante. Simplemente eliminandolo se ha solucionado